# How to drag and drop card between RecyclerViews like trello

Tags: android

[trello horizontal list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVUn1.png)

I  try this code but it drags in the same RecyclerView (up & down). but I need to move the card between RecyclerViews like trello. can you help?

here is my code:

```
  class CardAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder>(), ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    
        private val cardItemList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    
        fun addCard(cardName: String) {
            cardItemList.add(cardName)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false)
            return CardViewHolder(view)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val cardName = cardItemList[position]
            holder.bind(cardName)
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return cardItemList.size
        }
    
        class CardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            private val textViewCardName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.innerCardName)
    
            fun bind(cardName: String) {
                textViewCardName.text = cardName
    
            }
    
        }
    
        override fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): Boolean {
            Collections.swap(cardItemList, fromPosition, toPosition)
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
            return true
        }
    
        override fun onItemDismiss(position: Int) {
            cardItemList.removeAt(position)
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
        }
    }
```